# Can't figure out how this function works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a codecademy.com lesson that uses jQuery to create a color picker, which the user can use to select the background and border color of a div. You can see what it's supposed to look like here (at exercise 4-3).    http://www.codecademy.com/courses/basic-jquery/3#!/exercises/2  There's basically a row of colored boxes that you click on to choose the color of the different attributes of the main div. In total, there are three rows (each with many colored boxes) to choose the color of the three attributes of the div that we can style.

My question concerns the makeColorOption function. It's adding a class "colorOption" for the color parameter, however, I don't ever see this function called with a color passed to it. I'm assuming it must be called once for each color in the array, but I don't see that happening anywhere.

Can anyone explain if I'm missing something?

```
        $('document').ready(function(){

   //make the color pickers
   var colors = ['red','green','blue','yellow','black','white'];

   function makeColorOption(color) {
       return $('<div/>')
                    .addClass("colorOption")
                    .html(color)
                    .css('background-color',color);
   }

   $.each(colors,function(i,v) {
       $('div.colorPicker').append(
           $('<div/>')
                    .addClass("colorOption")
                    .html(v)
                    .css('background-color',v)
        );
   });

    $('div.colorPicker').append($('<div/>').addClass('clearfix'));


    $('div.colorOption').click(function(){

        var $this = $(this);

        var target = $this.closest('div.colorPicker').data('styleTarget');
        switch(target) {
            case 'background-color':
                setBackgroundColor($('#toy'),$this.html());
                break;
            case 'text-color':
                setTextColor($('#toy'),$this.html());
                break;
            case 'border-color':
                setBorderColor($('#toy'),$this.html());
                break;
            default:
                alert('hi');
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Read the docs on [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each)

Comment: is there a reason you don't just use javascript's native for(var in object) iterator?

Comment: I thought about the each function, but it doesn't call makeColorOption. How does .each associate the function in its parameters with makeColorOption?

Comment: @SamGrondahl I didn't create this

Comment: @zzzzBov the documentation doesn't explain how .each knows that makeColorOption is the callback.

Comment: @user1647484: What makes you think `.each` calls `makeColorOption` ? The `each` already creates and appends a `div` with the class `colorOption` to a `div` with a class `colorPicker` for each color specified in the `color` array. After that it attaches a click event to all `div` with the class `colorOption`, the ones just created with the `each`. `makeColorOption` is never used.

Comment: @user1647484 From the code you showed us, there's no relation between `makeColorOption` and `.each`. You can test this out by removing (or commenting out) the `makeColorOption` function and see if the script keeps working anyway.

Comment: I don't think this answer needed to be downvoted so heavily, the OP is just looking for some help, and has made a decent effort to explain the problems faced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything, the `makeColorOption` function is not used. The color pickers are being created by the `$.each(colors,function(i,v)` loop, whose body duplicates what `makeColorOption` does.

You could change that loop to:

```
   $.each(colors,function(i,v) {
       $('div.colorPicker').append(makeColorOption(v));
   });
```

and it would be equivalent.